# Flutter version information not used by Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter

In my iOS project, I have the following settings in the `Runner -> General` tab, under the `Identity` section:

```
Version: $(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)
Build:   $(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)
```

which is the same as when creating a brand new Flutter project. However, when I was going to create an Archive for releasing my app, Xcode complained that those fields were missing or incorrect (I don't remember the exact error message).

The only way I could build the release app was to change them to hardcoded strings - i.e. `1.0.0` and `1` respectively. What could be causing this issue? It would be a nuisance to have to remember to update those for every release, and I shouldn't have to, right?

Comment: so did you fix that?

Comment: @KirillKarmazin I did, but unfortunately I don't remember exactly what fixed it. I think I followed the answer by Günter Zöchbauer. But it could also have been something else, I remember messing around with the Podfile to fix some other issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created this project with an older Flutter version
several files created in the `ios/` and `android/` sub-directories might be outdated.

Newer Flutter versions might generate these files a bit differently and projects created with older Flutter versions might cause issues.

**Ways to fix**

Delete the `ios/` and `android/` directories and run `flutter create .` to re-generate these directories.

**HINT**
Custom changes will be lost and need to be re-applied. This is easiest if the project is committed to a version control system like Git.

Comment: Is this the only way?

Comment: It's not the only way, but I think it's the easiest.

Comment: Well be warned that this will delete any changes you've made to the ios/AppDelete.m file (adding Firebase) and your android/build.gradle file changes

Comment: If you use version control it should be easy to verify what changes are yours and need to be migrated and what changes are from Flutter updates and should be taken as-is.